# VueJS transition on computed values

Tags: vue.js, transition

I want to animate a block with posts that can be filtered.

Some filters trigger a computed method `filteredPosts` and they are assigned to a component liek that `<block-article :posts="filteredPosts" />`

In my `<block-article>` component I have something like that :

```
<template>
    <div class="posts">
      <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I want div `.posts` animate like a translation bottom/fade out  on disappear and translation top/ fade in on appear.

I tried that :

```
<template>
    <transition name="slide-fade">
        <div class="posts">
          <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id"></div>
        </div>
    </transition>
</template>
```

with corresponding css classes but it doesn't work.

I tried that :

```
<template>
    <div class="posts">
        <transition-group name="slide-fade">
          <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id"></div>
        </transition-group>
    </div>
</template>
```

but my class `.posts` is a grid and here I lost the grid behavior.

**THE AIM** is to animate the entire div `.posts` rather than each elements of the `v-for`.

Any idea ?

Thanks all,

Comment: Exact @StevenB. Thanks it works but finally it's a problem because transition not affect post which are in multiple filters so I need to animate the global div :/

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the bottom of your post.  If you want the global block to transition together then you need to use the `transition` tag.  If you want it to transition on the initial load you probably need to use`<transition name="slide-fade" appear><div class="posts"></div></transition>`

Comment: Arf it doesn't work when I change filters so when filteredPosts computed.

Answer (score 0):

If you animate entire div, you should use `transition`, but in this case all inner elements not animated. If you want to animate all inner elements. You should use `transition-group`

In your case I think, need use all this method with build-in `tag` attribute.
Becouse in dock you can read
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

> Unlike `transition`, it renders an actual element: a `span` by default. You can change the element that’s rendered with the tag attribute.

So you can write like this(its not full code, you must add `name, key` and other attrs)

```
<transition>
     <transition-group tag="div" class="posts">
        <div v-for="post in posts"></div>
    </transition-group>
</transition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieve this with :

```
<transition name="slide-fade">
    <div :key="posts.length" class="posts"></div>
</transition>
```

Nothe the `:key="posts.length"`

The problem is when `posts.length` doesn't change but it works in a lots of case. I will search how to fix this exception.